# Adicionar e remover item favorito com Cookie

Tags: php

Tenho o código para salvar o *cookie* pegando o `id` da postagem

```
$id= "5100";
setcookie("itemfavorito", $id, time()+3600*24*30*12*1);
```

Mas eu queria uma ajuda que é como fazer para quando a pessoa for em outra página com outro `id` ele salvar junto ficando assim lá no *cookie* salvo `5100/5101/5102` e assim vai...

Sei que deve ser com `explode`/`implode`, mas não sei como aplicar.

E também na hora de remover o *cookie* da página, como iria ser? Para remover o valor certo da página que seria por exemplo `5101`

Comment: Curiosidade: para que servirá este *cookie*?

Comment: Para adicionar a página que a pessoa adicionou nos favoritos, pegando o ID da página... igual a este site thenightfilmes.net 
é com cookie, mas não estou conseguindo fazer um com base nele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Para "adicionar" um valor a um cookie, tudo o que você precisa fazer é ler o valor atual que foi enviado a você com a solicitação atual, adicionar os novos dados e definir o resultado como um cookie com a mesma chave.

Em cada pagina basta mudar o valor da variável `$id` e incluir a pagina `setar_cookie.php`

**Paginas**

```
$id= "5100";
include("setar_cookie.php");
```

**setar_cookie.php**

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["itemfavorito"])) {
    setcookie("itemfavorito", $id, time()+3600*24*30*12*1, "/");
} else if (strpos($_COOKIE["itemfavorito"],$id)===false){
    $addId= $_COOKIE["itemfavorito"]."/".$id;
    setcookie("itemfavorito", $addId, time()+3600*24*30*12*1, "/");
}
```

**Para remover o valor certo da página**

```
$cookie= $_COOKIE['itemfavorito'];
//exemplo remover 5101

$id= join('/',array_diff(explode('/', $cookie), array('5101')));

setcookie("itemfavorito", $id, time()+3600*24*30*12*1, "/");
```

[**no ideone**](https://ideone.com/W2PN9e)

> **OBS:** A `/` (barra) no `setcookie` serve para indicar que funcione para todo o site e não apenas o diretório onde está sendo configurado [**setcookie**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php)

---

**Caso queira manter o cookie sempre ordenado**

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["itemfavorito"])) {
    setcookie("itemfavorito", $id, time()+3600*24*30*12*1, "/");
} else if (strpos($_COOKIE["itemfavorito"],$id)===false){
        $addId= $_COOKIE["itemfavorito"]."/".$id;
        $array= explode("/",$addId);
        sort($array);
        $joinId= join('/',$array); 
        setcookie("itemfavorito", $joinId, time()+3600*24*30*12*1, "/");
}
```

---

### E se tiver um ID "5101" adicionado e se for adicionar outro "510"

> Nesse caso podemos usar:

**setar_cookie.php**

```
$tags = $_COOKIE["itemfavorito"];
$tagsArray = explode('/', $tags);

if(!isset($_COOKIE["itemfavorito"])) {
    setcookie("itemfavorito", $id, time()+3600*24*30*12*1, "/");
} else if (!in_array($id, $tagsArray)) {
        $addId= $_COOKIE["itemfavorito"]."/".$id;
        $array= explode("/",$addId);
        sort($array);
        $joinId= join('/',$array); 
        setcookie("itemfavorito", $joinId, time()+3600*24*30*12*1, "/");
}
```

Comment: Testei aqui mas ficou meio embolado, eu acesso uma página ai adiciona o cookie com inicio ; ai depois adiciona ;/5101
eu estou tentando fazer isso com base nesse site thenightfilmes.net ele usa exatamente como estou tentando, mas tá meio complicado fazer

Comment: @RogérioSilva, para desembolar, tens que postar o código que você fez

Comment: Adicionei do jeito que colocou ai no exemplo, o primeiro código na página assim que a pessoa clica ai adiciona nos favoritos, mas adiciona "/" e ";" no cookie também, o exemplo que eu quero está nesse site thenightfilmes.net ele fez essa função, mas não consigo fazer um com base nele

Comment: Funcionou, pode me ajudar em outra coisa? se a pessoa entrar em uma pagina com o ID que já está salvo no cookie, mostrar uma mensagem ex:  SALVA EM FAVORITOS

Comment: Sim, mas de que forma, um alerta, um modal? Ou simplesmente um echo?

Comment: Um echo normal, com um aviso que foi salvo nos favoritos a pagina visitada

Comment: @RogérioSilva, tanto no `if`quanto no `else` coloque `$favoritado = "Esta página foi salva nos favoritos";` Daí é só dar um `echo $favoritado;` no local que quer exibir o aviso.

Comment: Dessa forma funciona, mostra a mensagem de que foi salva, mas o que eu queria era quando entrar na pagina com tal ID verifica se tem no cookie esse valor salvo ai mostra a mensagem PAGINA FAVORITADA ou NAO FAVORITADA

Comment: @RogérioSilva, ai muda o foco da pergunta que é `como fazer para quando a pessoa for em outra página com outro id ele salvar junto ficando assim lá no cookie salvo 5100/5101/5102 e assim vai...`. Para que mostre PAGINA FAVORITADA ou NAO FAVORITADA deveria ter na página um botão para o usuário clicar e salvar o cookie para que a pagina faça parte dos favoritos. Enquanto ele não clicar no botão vai aparecer a mensagem NAO FAVORITADA. Nesse caso melhor fazer outra pergunta relatando essa situação para que esse post não fique confuso para os demais usuarios.

Comment: Era exatamente isso... O botão já está funcionando normal, mas como faço para quando a pagina já estiver favoritada, o botão mudar para Não Favoritar

Comment: Na setar_cookie.php coloca esse linha de código `if (strpos($_COOKIE["itemfavorito"],$id)!==false){$desabilitar = "disabled";}` e no botão `<button type="button" .... <?php echo $desabilitar; ?>>.....</button>`

Comment: funcionou, muito obrigado. Mas o que eu percebi é que na hora de adicionar o ID no cookie, se tiver um ID "5101" adicionado e se for adicionar outro "510" não pega

Comment: @RogérioSilva, resposta editada